# Как соединить несколько таблиц sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Имеется две таблицы: `user, proc_leader`.

Первая таблица состоит из имен:

```
 uid| username| salary|  
 ---+---------+-------+
 1  | beny    | 0     |
 2  | barikan | 0     |
```

Вторая таблица `proc_leader` состоит из `foreign key`:

```
 projectNo| process | proc_leader|  
 ---------+---------+------------+
 1610004  | ANM BLD | beny       |
 1610004  | BGD CUP | barikan    |
 1610005  | ANM BLD | bob        |
 1610006  | BGD CUP | barikan    |
```

Все данные в этой таблице являются `foreign key` к другим таблицам:

- projectNo foreign key в таблице project
- process foreign key в таблице theme_name
- proc_leader foreign key в таблице user

Я хочу вывести с помощью sql каждое имя из таблицы `user`, каждый процесс и номер проекта, которому он присвоен. Например, что-то такое:

```
 uid| username| projectNo| process| 
 ---+---------+----------+--------+
 1  | beny    | 1610004  |ANM BLD |
 1  | beny    | 1610004  |BGD CUP |
 2  | bob     | 1610005  |ANM BLD |
 2  |barikan  | 1610006  |BGD CUP |
```

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Возьмите какой нибудь начальный учебник по sql, например на sql-ex.ru. Ваш вопрос относится к базовым знаниям SQL, которые получаются за 1 день

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, обычным join'ом:

```
SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN proc_leader pl ON (username = pl.proc_leader)
```

И ещё я бы в proc_leader использовал не имя, а uid: имена ведь есть уже в user

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [**соединение таблиц**](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html):

```
select u.uid, u.username, pl.projectNo, pl.process
from user u join proc_leader pl on u.username = pl.proc_leader
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/427967/1/0).